# Is it possible to inject events in the event viewer in an old date

Tags: windows, windows-xp, event-log, windows-server, event-viewer

I need to know if anyone can inject events in event viewer logs in an old date, how event viewer data are stored, and can anyone change them?

Comment: That would be a security violation: Falsification of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you can't do this on a running system, but the Windows Event Log format has been reverse engineered to the point that you could probably do it offline; perhaps somebody has written a tool for it.  [Here is one analysis.](http://code.google.com/p/libevt/downloads/detail?name=Windows%20Event%20Log%20%28EVT%29.pdf)